# javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, apache-axis

I got this exception while invoking .net web service using Axis2. Please help me to find out solution.

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:123)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:67)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:354)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at com.cakemarketing.affiliates.api._2.ReportsStub.clicks(ReportsStub.java:2106)
at com.infotop.common.Test.main(Test.java:49)

Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:276)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMContainerHelper.buildNext(OMContainerHelper.java:164)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMContainerHelper.getFirstOMChild(OMContainerHelper.java:182)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getFirstOMChild(OMDocumentImpl.java:201)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:98)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:544)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:540)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:188)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:145)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:108)
... 7 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed
at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:36)
at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.next(SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.java:138)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:651)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:189)
... 16 more
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That exception is triggered when the response from the server contains a document type declaration, which is not allowed in SOAP. This usually means that the server generated an HTML error page instead of a SOAP response.